# Maxscript Python addModifier

Tags: python, maxscript

I'm writing maxscript in python and the following code throws a type error:

```
import MaxPlus

res = MaxPlus.Core.GetRootNode()
#This is just as example that I use the first child.
child = MaxPlus.INode.GetChild(res,0)

morpherFP = MaxPlus.FPValue()
MaxPlus.Core.EvalMAXScript("Morpher()", morpherFP)
morpher = MaxPlus.FPValue.Get(morpherFP)

MaxPlus.INode.AddModifier(child, morpher)
```

And from the MaxScript Listener I always receive the following error:

> type 'exceptions.TypeError' in method 'INode_AddModifier', argument 2 of type 'Autodesk::Max::Modifier'"

while the type of morpher is Animatable(Morpher) and Animatable is a subclass of Modifier. Could someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a possible solution  (The only thing I know is that the MaxScript Listener doesn't throw an error):

```
import MaxPlus

res = MaxPlus.Core.GetRootNode()
#I use the first child as example
child = MaxPlus.INode.GetChild(res,0)
morpher = MaxPlus.Factory.CreateObjectModifier(MaxPlus.ClassIds.Morpher)
MaxPlus.INode.AddModifier(child, morpher) 
# the following also seems to work aka it does not throw any errors
child.InsertModifier(morpher,1)
```

Let me know if it is not correct or there is an easier or more understandable way.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way to create a morpher modifier.